# Getting a list of values from dynamically created nested divs and selects angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently running into a problem with the application I'm writing. I would like to retrieve a two different lists from dynamically created div and select elements.

```
<form (submit)="updateReviewerForIssue()">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row header blue">
      <div class="cell">Key</div>
      <div class="cell">Summary</div>
      <div class="cell">Reviewer</div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="reviews.issues.length === 0" class="row">
      <div class="cell" data-title="Key">No reviews at this time.</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Summary"></div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Reviewer"></div>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let issue of reviews.issues;">
      <div class="row" #row>
        <!--Retrieve list of the issueKey-->
        <div class="cell keyHolder" data-title="Key" #key id="{{issue.key}}" style="min-width: 175px;">
          {{issue.key}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Summary">{{issue.fields.summary}}</div>
        <div class="cell select" data-title="Reviewer" #reviewer>
          <!--Retrieve list of the selected displayName-->
          <select class="review">
            <option disabled selected hidden>Select a user..</option>
            <option *ngFor="let user of users" id="{{user.displayName}}" value={{user.displayName}}>
              {{user.displayName}}
            </option>
          </select>
          <div class="select__arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <ng-template #showEmptyList>
          <select>
            <option>No users found</option>
          </select>
          <div class="select__arrow"></div>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <input value="Assign Users For Review" type="submit" class="btn btn-green float-right">
</form>
```

The lists I'm after are the the issue.key list and the selected displayName list.

I have tried getting it by row.querySelectorAll('.select'), but then I get an error that I can't do this on an undefined object.

Anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Your solution might not be that simple. I did something similar using this step by step example and it worked great.https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: Alright, thanks for your reply. I'll give it a shot!